# Appengine Cloud Endpoints & core data

Tags: core-data, google-cloud-endpoints

When using Cloud Endpoints generated libs, is there anyway to use core data without manually creating models?  Is there any easy way to integrate the two so the objects from the endpoint can be persisted with core data?

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to your question? I have a similar problem with locally persisting Cloud Endpoint messages: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25817671/appengine-cloud-endpoint-messages-and-ios-core-data?lq=1

Comment: No, I have had to manually adapt the entities as @Mundi suggested.  Would have been nice to avoid with extra code, but it is not a huge amount of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any generic solution. It seems to me that the two philosophies - Appengine Cloud Endpoints as a relational database vs. Core Data as an object graph - are just to different to facilitate a solution without any manual adaptation.

So there is no "easy way to integrate the two". That being said, if you write your own conversion solution, the most complicated part seems to be the change from foreign keys to relationships. Apart from that it should not be too difficult.